# How to use meta query for greater than value in array?

Tags: meta-query

I have saved some price values of three products in a custom field name roomprice. Meta keys and values are like here:

```
**product first** 
post_id = 1432
meta_key = roomprice
meta_value = a:3:{i:0;s:1:"4";i:1;s:1:"5";i:2;s:1:"9";}

**product second**
post_id = 1433
meta_key = roomprice
meta_value = a:3:{i:0;s:1:"8";i:1;s:2:"10";i:2;s:2:"12";}

**product third**
post_id = 1434
meta_key = roomprice
meta_value = a:3:{i:0;s:2:"15";i:1;s:2:"16";i:2;s:1:"4";}
```

where 4, 5,9  are the three prices of product first,

8,10,12 are the three  prices of product second,

15,16,4 are the three  prices of product third.

Now I want to use a meta query to search products where
price will be greater than 10.

How can I use meta query to search in array and greater than the stored values.

Comment: With difficulty. Why not store each price as a separate entry under the same meta key, and then use a simple `meta_query` with `WP_Query` - way easier and far more efficient performance-wise.

Comment: How? Can you please explain?

Comment: How are you currently saving `roomprice`?

Comment: @VijayLal did you ever find a solution to this?